# How to workaround the Automaton unable to install the radar beacon bug?

Tags: fallout-4, fallout-4-automatron

I am stuck on the Automaton quest line "A new threat" as I cannot install the radar beacon on Ada. There seems to be a bug if you build the robotic workbench directly after meeting Ada. I can only upgrade her legs.

As I am on PC, I tried looking for a workaround using console commands.

[I found possible approach to reset the questline](http://www.nexusmods.com/fallout4/mods/11236/?) via:

```
GetStage  01000801
completeallobjectives 01000801
CompleteQuest 01000801
```

and to start the Headhunter questline via:

```
ShowQuestStages  01002833
SetStage 01002833 150
```

Yet it seeems that the quest ids do not work for me as the `GetStage` command only yields in `Item '01000801' not found for parameter quest`.

How to proceed the quest line using the console? I know that I can resort to a save, yet I rather not lose my current progress I made in between the Automaton quests.

Comment: Have you tried building another workbench?

Comment: @DCShannon Yes, I scraped the first one and rebuild a second one. It did not change the behavior. It has a questmarker on it, yet nothing besides leg mods can be applied for Ada.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Robots.esm` needs to be directly below `Fallout4.esm` in your load order for those bat files (or commands) to work. For instance, if you have another mod in between the command will only work if it is typed `GetStage 02000801`, if you have two mods in between it'll be `03000801`, etc. I'm not suggesting that you retype the commands, the easiest way to resolve the issue is just to move `Robots.esm` directly below `Fallout4.esm` so that all its records begin with `01` and not `02` or  `03`, etc.

Also, a poster in the thread of the mod you linked to said:

> not sure if anyone has mentioned this but by shooting ada until she needs a repair kit, then use one on her. Thats all it took to fix it for me.

If this is true, obviously it'll be the easiest, least invasive way to work around the issue. (confirmed working by OP)

If you have the 2nd inspirational perk and cannot damage Ada, you can still either try the first method or open the console and type:

```
player.removeperk 001d2462
```

Then damage and fix her, then type:

```
player.addperk 001d2462
```

According to k0pernikus, even if you have the third perk you only need to remove the 2nd perk for this to work.

Comment: Ada is my companion and I have the second Inspirational perk which makes companions immune against my attacks.

Comment: Edited my answer to address this issue.

Comment: @k0pernikus Can you damage her if you dismiss her first?

Comment: Removing the perk and then shooting Ada to defunction and repairing her gave me the full possibility of upgrading her. You are a savegame-saver :D

Comment: And in fact, I had all three Inspirational perks and I only needed to remove the 2nd one.

Comment: Good to hear, I edited my post with your info about not needing to remove the 3rd perk.

Answer (score 1):

If you encounter the glitch where you can't access Ada's parts, when you just see the legs in Workbench, you need to the console and choose Ada with a pointer and run `recycleactor`.

---

(From an attempt to edit in another answer into the main question: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/310142 )

Comment: This was the one that solved it for me, but in addition while I still had Ada selected I also ran `moveto player` so that I could then put her in the workbench.

Answer (score -1):

This seemed to work fine, for me:

```
completeallobjectives 01000801

SetStage 01000801 2900
```